# Check if someones connected to PC through Windows RDP

Tags: windows, rdp

Is there any way to tell whether someone is already connected to a computer through Windows' "Remote Desktop Connection"? Me and a co-worker need to remotely connect to a PC in our remote office, and we keep kicking each other out of the session when trying to connect (if the other one is connected). Could you perhaps check if the RDP port 3389 is in use?

Comment: Windows will ask the current user if he wants to allow "the other user" to connect, he can approve or deny the request

Comment: I'll look through the settings but as of now it doesn't, it just kicks out whoever's using the PC without a prompt or warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can list remote sessions with `qwinsta`:

```
c:\> qwinsta /SERVER:<YOUR-MACHINE>
```

Id #1 is the local session.